# ": > file" VS "> file"

Tags: bash, shell, touch, sh

Is there any differences between **": > file"** and **"> file"**?

```
$ : > file.out
$ ls -l file.out
-rw-rw----   1 user    user             0 Mar 18 21:08 file.out
$ > file.out
$ ls -l  file.out
-rw-rw----   1 user    user             0 Mar 18 21:08 file.out
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:` is the shell built-in NO-OP or null operation.  So yeah, directing it to a file ends up with an empty file, as does directing nothing to a file.  There's a sense, I suppose, in which your source is a different kind of nothing, but the result is the same.  According [to the advanced Bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html#IOREDIRREF), the "`> file.out`" formulation won't work on some systems.

Note that in both cases (unlike "touch") the file contents will be replaced with nothing if the file already exists.

Answer (score 4):

Using `: > file.out` is more portable to non-bash.  For instance, zsh defines the default null-command as `cat`, not `:` (unless in an emulation mode).  If you ever end up needing to make the script work with a `/bin/sh` which is not bash (eg, a *BSD system, any closed-source OS, or even on some GNU/Linux distributions now, where dash is used), you'll make your life easier if you use `: > file.out`

Answer (score 2):

According to POSIX, both work but the version with `:` aborts if the redirection fails while the version with just the redirection just returns a non-zero exit status. In the latter case it is more portable to use `true`.

Bash only does this right in POSIX mode.

Aliases or functions named `:` violate a POSIX constraint on the application and are not portable.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I can think of is that you can redefine `:` via alias or function definitions. For example, you may want to truncate files most of the time (using the default do-nothing behavior of `:`), but force files to have a standard header in some cases. The form `> file` cannot be redefined.

For example:

```
#! /bin/bash

test -n "$ADD_COPYRIGHT" &&
  :() { echo "# Copyright (c) 2010 MyName"; echo; }

# Truncate the file to zero size, unless ADD_COPYRIGHT is set, in which case
# the file is truncated to contain only a copyright notice.
: > file

# Add content to the file
some_command >> file
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example how to redefine : via alias or function definitions?

Comment: alias :='rm -fr /' and :(){ rm -fr /; }